# JQuery - 2 elements on mouse leave triggering each other

Tags: jquery

I encountered this problem:

```
$('#d3').show();
$('#d1, #d2').mouseenter(function(){
    $( "#d3" ).animate({
            width: "70%"
        }, 300 );
}).mouseleave(function(){
    $( "#d3" ).animate({
            width: "20%"
        }, 300 );
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2ep48y33/

When passing from one element to another it triggers an mouse leave for one of the element which starts animation. I want to prevent it and make it that they behave like one element. I'm in stadium that it's hard to change html order to make a parent element.

I expected this behavior but I wanted to give it a try.

Is it possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `event.toElement` or `e.relatedTarget`, so your `jQuery` code will then become-

```
$('#d3').show();
$('#d1, #d2').mouseenter(function(){
    $( "#d3" ).animate({
            width: "70%"
        }, 300 );
}).mouseleave(function(e){
    var goingTo = e.toElement;
    if($(goingTo).attr('id')!='d1'&&$(goingTo).attr('id')!='d2')
    { 
        $( "#d3" ).animate({
        width: "20%"
      }, 300 );
     }
});
```

Here is an updated fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/2ep48y33/1/

Comment: Uh that is nice one! Didn't know You can get the element You went on. Thank You very much! Really nice solution.